# How to get the common first substrings In two Strings

Tags: java

I need some help, I have two Strings  and I want to get the first occurrence of common substrings.

```
1st String : abacdefghi
2nd String : abaciopiss
```

I want to get the substring

```
substring : abac
```

Thank you everyone.

Comment: Loop over each string concurrently. If characters match, add to resultant string and keep going. Otherwise break out of the loop and return the resultant sub string.

Comment: Show your attempt first, SO community is not for doing your work, It's to help each other in particular cases of programs. !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It maybe isn't the best solution but my attempt would be to find the first matching characters in each string and then continue to check the following characters if they are still the same:

```
private static String extractFirstEqual(String a, String b) {

    //Split your string into an array of characters
    String[] arr = a.split("");
    String[] brr = b.split("");
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    //Iterate over both arrays
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < brr.length; j++) {
            //Find first matching character
            if (arr[i].equals( brr[j])) {
                //While there are more characters in both arrays and the characters keep matching, append them
                // to the result
                while (arr[i].equals(brr[j]) && i < arr.length && j < brr.length) {
                    result.append(arr[i]);
                    i++;
                    j++;
                }

                return result.toString();
            }
        }
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```